# Arc length from edge of circle

Tags: geometry, functions

[image]

Suppose y is the diameter of the circle above.How would I find the length of s in the circle? Obviously I can't use the formula $s=\theta r$ because the angle isn't central.

Comment: *Hint*. The "central angle" is equal to $2\theta$.

Comment: Could you please explain why?

Comment: Oh wait nvm, I see it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar formula for angles that have their vertex on the perimeter of the circle: they are called ["inscribed angles"](https://mathbitsnotebook.com/Geometry/Circles/CRAngles.html) and the formula is almost identical to the central angle formula. We see from the formula that $m\angle XY = \theta = \frac{1}{2} m\angle S$, so $m\angle S = 2\theta$.

Comment: I don't understand this notation. Could you please tell me what m∠XY and m∠S mean?

Comment: @Jonathan It means "the angle under which arc XY is seen seen from m" (it is not a standard notation)